# user mode linux - how to create 32-bit linux

Tags: linux, kernel

i am trying to compile my own UML kernel. I achieved to created a ./linux executable, however this is 64bit on my 32 bit system.

```
file vmlinux
vmlinux: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped

uname -a
Linux testbox 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Wed Jun 17 16:11:42 UTC 2015 i686 GNU/Linux
```

For making the kernel i executed:

```
make ARCH=um defconfig
make -j4 linux ARCH=um
```

How can i enforce to get a 32bit executable? Is there an additional parameter for make?

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself, in the kernel config (make menuconfig ARCH=um) it is possible to set 64bit Kernel - or unset it => so that I get a 32bit executable.